# Artifacts mapping OpenGL scene using spherical coordinates

Tags: opengl, projection, perspectivecamera

My objective is to generate a **seamless** 2D view of a 360 scene using spherical coordinates. Each column represents an orientation and each row a angle of elevation while the value of each pixel the depth. To achieve this I followed this procedure (as suggested by one of the comments below):

1. I generated a depth cubemap (i.e. a cubemap with depth information).
2. I then sampled the cubemap using spherical coordinates.

However, the result I get clearly show the seams of the cubemap I sampled from.

[image]

I am uncertain to what extent this is due to the fact that OpenGL projects everything into a plane so some information, e.g. depth, gets more distorted towards the edges of each cube side and/or due directly to the seams of the cubemap. I would like to try to avoid these artifacts.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to avoid this?

FYI the fragment shader I used to sample the depth cubemap is the following,

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec2 size_display;
uniform float hrange;
uniform float vrange;
uniform samplerCube depthcube;

out float color;

void main()
{
    // scale coordinates (0,1)
    vec2 scaleCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / size_display;

    // center the view
    vec2 angles = ((scaleCoord * 2.0) - vec2(1.0)) * vec2(radians(hrange/2), radians(vrange/2));

    // sampling vector
    vec3 samplingVec = vec3(-cos(angles.y) * cos(angles.x), sin(angles.y), cos(angles.y) * sin(angles.x));

    // output
    color = texture(depthcube, samplingVec).r;
```

`hrange` refers to horizontal angular range (typically 360) though here is 180. An `vrange` refers to vertical angular range.

Comment: Could this not be done with a bit of math in the vertex shader?

Comment: Render a rectilinear projection (times six if you want to cover the entire sphere with a cube-map); then run a compute (or fragment) shader that for each pixel in the spherical map samples the correct spot in the rectilinear image. You can scale the depth according to the location of the sample on the rectilinear image. Please include some specifics in your question if you want to get a proper answer.